# How to open remote path pdf in webview xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I am working in xamarin.forms. I got HTML content as josn Response.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- CALL: theme('node') --> <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS: * node--253.tpl.php * node--article.tpl.php x node.tpl.php -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/templates/node.tpl.php' -->
<div id="node-253" class="node node-article clearfix" about="/maharastracmo/en/magazines" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">
    <h2> <a href="/maharastracmo/en/magazines">Magazine Gallery</a> </h2>
    <span property="dc:title" content="Magazine Gallery" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
    <span property="sioc:num_replies" content="0" datatype="xsd:integer" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
                <div class="innerContent">
                    <div class="pdfBlock">
                        <div class="pdfIconBox">
                            <a href="http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/pdf/MA-June15-binder-6.pdf" target="_blank">
                                <img alt="" src="http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/images/book-icon.png" />
                            </a>
                            <h5>Maharashtra Ahead</h5> <span class="bookDate">June 2015</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- END OUTPUT from 'sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/templates/node.tpl.php' -->
```

In this content there is one image and on when user click on image .pdf is open in new browser.

**I create html and display that html in WebView but on image click pdf file is doesn't open. pdf file is comes from remote device. (Server).**

***Second Try :***

**As a second option I have taken webview and simply put pdf remote path as source property but blank page is open. How can I solve this problem?**

***Third Try :***

**I simply use one button and on button click event pdf path is open in another browser. but doesn't open instead pdf file is directly download.**

```
protected async void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/sites/all/themes/maharastracmonew/pdf/MA-June15-binder-6.pdf");
            Device.OpenUri(uri);
        }
```

Comment: On iOS 9.0+ ATS restrictions are put in place to block non-HTTPS references by default. Look in the Output window for network errors. You can look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/#Opting-Out_of_ATS) to find out how to exclude specific URLs from these restrictions. On Android, WebViews are not able to open PDFs by default. You will need to download them first before being able to display them.

Comment: On which platform you are experiencing this problem? On Android? The `WebView` from Android doesn't support it out of the box. You need `loadUrl`, which you only get with a dependency service or something.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use Xamarin Dependency Service. Here is how I did it.

First Define an interface:

```
namespace Mobile.DependencyService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public interface IDownload
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <param name="bytes"></param>
        /// <param name="fullPathToSavedFile"></param>
        void Save(string name, byte[] bytes, out string fullPathToSavedFile);
    }
}
```

Inside your click event: var uri = your link to the pdf;

```
var uri = repository.GetResumeUri(model);

  if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
  {
    using (var clientHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler())
    {
       using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(clientHandler))
       {
           httpClient.BaseAddress = uri;
           byte[] bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
           var service = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<Mobile.DependencyService.IDownload>();

           string fullPathToSavedFile;
           service.Save(
                        String.Format("{0}.pdf", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")), //String.Format("{0} Resume.pdf", model.Type),
                         bytes,
                         out fullPathToSavedFile
                         );

           uri = new Uri(String.Format("file://{0}", fullPathToSavedFile));
        }
     }
  }
  Device.OpenUri(uri);
```

In iOS:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Mobile.iOS.DependencyService.Download))]
namespace Mobile.iOS.DependencyService
{
    public class Download : IDownload
    {
      public void Save(string name, byte[] bytes, out string fullPathToSavedFile)
        {
            fullPathToSavedFile = String.Empty;

            try
            {
             fullPathToSavedFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), name);

                File.WriteAllBytes(fullPathToSavedFile, bytes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var ex1 = ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Mobile.Droid.DependencyService.Download))]
namespace Mobile.Droid.DependencyService
{
   public class Download : IDownload
    {
       public void Save(string name, byte[] bytes, out string fullPathToSavedFile)
        {
            fullPathToSavedFile = String.Empty;
            // https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Environment+SpecialFolder/
            // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

            try
            {

                //var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), name);
                using(var directory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads))
                {
                    if (null != directory) 
                    {
                        var state = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageState(directory);

                        if (String.Compare(state, Android.OS.Environment.MediaMounted,true)==0)
                        {
                            fullPathToSavedFile = Path.Combine(directory.AbsolutePath, name);
                            File.WriteAllBytes(fullPathToSavedFile, bytes);

                            //File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(directory.AbsolutePath, name), bytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var ex1 = ex;
            }
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: I don't want to save file. I just want to open file.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the data is cached and it is deleted after.